# Refresh values of Django app in Docker (Cloudron)

Tags: python, django, docker

So I have some Python knowledge, but am a complete beginner with Django and Docker.

My problem is the following: I packaged a very basic Django app into a Docker app (actually a Cloudron app, Cloudron is a solution based on Docker). The app is now running on my server ([eth.ncollig.net](https://eth.ncollig.net)). It's purpose is to give me the price of Ether.

But the view.py script ran at the startup of the app on the server, the value of the variable, the price of ether in euros, has been set to 251.7, and it is never refreshed.

I would like the value of this variable to be recalculated at every new page load. What should I do to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Here's my views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from coinbase.wallet.client import Client

client = Client('yhKYHa8AkQaHXDMc','quspNs86vAvsRtyuGmE3nC5o9Nki2pqP')

rates = client.get_exchange_rates(currency='ETH')
eth_rate = rates['rates']['EUR']

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("1 ETH = %s EUR" % eth_rate)
```

Here's my start.sh, used to launch the gunicorn server:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start Gunicorn processes
echo Starting Gunicorn.
exec gunicorn ethprice.wsgi:application \
    --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 \
    --workers 3
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM cloudron/base:0.11.0
MAINTAINER Authors name <support@cloudron.io>

RUN mkdir -p /app/code
WORKDIR /app/code

COPY ethprice /app/code/
COPY start.sh /app/code/start.sh
COPY requirements.txt /app/code/requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["/app/code/start.sh"]
```

Here's wsgi.py:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ethprice.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', 'ethprice.views.index'),
]
```

Comment: The `index` function is called on every request. However, the `eth_rate` variable is set only once - during the initialization. You should move the `client.get_exchange_rates(currency='ETH')` (and the assignment to `eth_rate`) inside the `index` view function.

Comment: As simple as that...thanks!

Comment: Note, this has nothing to do with Docker, but would happen in any production environment.